# Is it possible to create a search function with a v-select alongside user input with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

What I am trying to achieve is that,when the user types in the search bar what they are looking for( for example if they want an account that starts with SAE), when the user clicks on the dropdown and selects one of the items(for example, Account), it should bring back a result with all the records that have the account of SAE.I have tried to implement an @change event from the v-select and it does recognize that I am selecting one of the items in the dropdown. I am not sure if it is possible because I have translated the items in the dropdown using Vuei18n.

The code below is for the search bar and dropdown list

```
<v-text-field
          v-model="searchField"
          :label="$t('searchPage.search')"
          placeholder="..."
          clearable
          clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
          class="mr-4"
          @keyup.enter="loader = 'loading'"
        />

<v-select
          v-show="standardSearch"
          :label="$t('searchPage.searchBy')"
          :items="selection"
          chips
          small-chips
          deletable-chips
          @change="searchByDropdown"
        />

//The code that is in the js file

data(){
const t = this.$t.bind(this);
return {
searchField:""
searchSelection:[
  t("searchPage.meterNumber"),
  t("searchPage.account"),
  t("searchPage.billingArea")
   ]
 }

}
```

And the below code is for the searchByDropdown event

```
searchByDropdown(e) {
      const t = this.$t.bind(this);
      var searchInput = `${this.searchField}`;
      var searchSelection = `${this.selection}`;
      debugger;
      // t("searchPage.meterNumber"),
      // t("searchPage.account"),
      // t("searchPage.billingArea")
      switch (e) {
        case searchInput && e == t("searchPage.meterNumber"):
          //After this I want to start searching
          debugger;
          break;

        case searchInput && e == t("searchPage.account"):
          break;

        case searchInput && e == t("searchPage.billingArea"):
          break;

        default:
          searchSelection == null;
      }
      console.log(e + searchInput);
    }
```

The search results will be displayed in a treeview, but I would want to know if this achievable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this. All i needed was a variable that stores the value of the dropdown and if that value matches the dropdowns value then I can use it to search for the data

```
//This is the dropdown search function

//The search key is a variable that will store the value of the dropdown hence 'e'

selection: [
        {
          name: t("searchPage.meterNumber"),
          value: "meterNumber"
        },
        {
          name: t("searchPage.account"),
          value: "account"
        },
        {
          name: t("searchPage.billingArea"),
          value: "billingArea"
        }
      ],

searchByDropdown(e) {
      debugger;
      this.searchKey = e;
      console.log(e);
    },

if (searchInput != "" && this.searchKey == "meterNumber") {
              this.$services.accountService
                .accountSearchMultiple({
                  organisationID: 0,
                  meterNumber: searchInput,
                  n: 100
                })
                .then(response => {
                  this.treeData = response.data.treeItems;
                  this.itemData = response.data.dataItems;
                  this.revealTree = false;
                  this.snackbar = {
                    message: "Your search is successful",
                    color: "success",
                    show: true
                  };
                })
                .catch(() => {
                  this.revealTree = true;
                  this.snackbar = {
                    message: "Invalid Search",
                    color: "error",
                    show: true
                  };
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

vuetify has its own built-in component named *"v-autocomplete"*. its exactly like *v-select* and a searchbar at the top enabling user to search through *Items* to find the most closest item to the searched text.